# Go to Questions in R Shiny or how to programm a check list/questionnaire

Tags: r, shiny

I am quite new to R shiny and I need the help of R shiny professions :)
I don't want to let the work other people do - but currently I need a starting point from where I can go on. This is my issue:
I want to programm a shiny app, where my input are questions, which have the user to answer. The questions are just Yes or No buttons (or something similar). There should be the option to go back to last questions for corrections. The answers are visible in the output. However, the upcoming questions are dependend on the previous answer. I try to visualize it by an example:

Question 1.0: Male or Female?

Answer: Male

Depending on the answer go to Question 1.1 or Question 1.2, Question 1 is now not visible anymore in the UI and was replaced by the next Question

Questions 1.1: Do you wear a beard?

Answer: Yes

Go to next Question (in respect to answer)

Question 1.11: Is the beard short or long?

Answer: Short

Go to next Question... and so on

In principle I would like to have finally a branching of sub-questions and answer are recorded.

Please could someone provide me with an example code, from where I can go on to programm my app? I am very thankful!

Thank you,
Martin

Comment: maybe this (https://github.com/EconometricsBySimulation/Shiny-Demos/tree/master/Survey) could help?

Comment: You're the best! Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was searching for!